# How to build join string by expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

all

Below is my query code:

```
var users = db.users.where(u=> u.id=5 && db.usergroups.any(d=>d.user_id=u.id))
```

Build the expression tree for the condition `u.id=5` is easy, but who can tell me how to build the condition `db.usergroups.any(d=>d.user_id=u.id)`

thanks

Comment: The code looks fine. What is the problem? Do you mean to build the expression tree by hand?

Comment: I mean, with calls to the static methods of the `Expression` class?

Comment: This code is static, I just want to convert it to dynamic query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to obtain the expression created by the C# compiler is to affect it to a variable of the correct type, and looking at it in a debugger; in your case:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> lambdaExpression =
    u => u.id == 5 && db.UserGroups.Any(d => d.user_id == u.id);
```

And then look at the `lambdaExpression` variable in a debugger.